# How to Validate Mobile number Starting digits in @Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

my code is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, true, null, new { @placeholder = "Enter Phone Number *", @minlength = "10", @maxlength = "12", @autocomplete = "off", @data_rule_number = true, @data_msg_number = "*invalid phone number", @class = "form-control" })
```

here I have to validate that the user should enter number starting with digits (6/7/8/9).
how to achieve that?

Comment: Hope the link below can help you to cope with.
[Add Regular expression to the razor view.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126373/how-to-set-regular-expressions-in-cshtml-razor-file-in-asp-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the pattern field:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, true, null, new { pattern = @"^([6-9][0-9]{9,11})$", @placeholder = "Enter Phone Number *", @minlength = "10", @maxlength = "12", @autocomplete = "off", @data_rule_number = true, @data_msg_number = "*invalid phone number", @class = "form-control" })
```

The pattern string `^([6-9][0-9]{9,11})$` means the first number can be 6 to 9, then users can use 0 to 9 to fill the remain numbers, and the length of remain numbers is from 9 to 11.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Removable's answer,in .net core
You could add the `[RegularExpression(@"^[6-9][0~9]{9,11}$", ErrorMessage = "CusRegularErrorMessage")]` Attribute on your Phone Property of the model for  both clientside validation and serverside validation

You could Check this document for more details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#built-in-attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern for 12 digits that's shown in below:

pattern = @"^(6|7|8|9)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$"